# How to create Circular View with shadow

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have needed to create view like [image] and this view will be placed like [image]

I am trying to create this using frame layout but finish with failure. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Either use a FrameLayout and add this as an imageview last with specified right and top layout margins for this view and some slightly larger right margins for the underlying layout.

Or a RelativeLayout and you align this view to the parent right using (`layout_alignParentRight="true"`) and with margins as with previous example.

Example trying to mimic your layout a bit, tweak the margins and image to your needs:

[image: This layout displays]

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#bbbb00"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#888899"
            android:layout_margin="20dp">
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/test"/>

</FrameLayout>
```